# Problem with add class on hover with equal data-id

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I need to change color title with equal data-id on hover img

```
   <div class="left_box">
      <div data-id="1">
          title 1
       </div>
       <div data-id="2">
          title 2
       </div>
       <div data-id="3">
          title 3
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_box">
        <a href="#" data-id="1">
           <img src="url_image">
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-id="3">
           <img src="url_image">
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-id="2">
           <img src="url_image">
        </a>
   </div>
```

On hover of `a[data-id="2"]` I need to change color of .left_box `div[data-id="2"]` in js or jquery. Can you help me?

Comment: CSS `:hover` should be useful.

Comment: How I can into css? I have about 20 data-id I need to insert 20 row into css? is not possible to js?

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve the desired result?

Comment: jQuery(".right_box a").mouseover(function() {
 jQuery(".left_box a[data-id='" + current +"').addClass("act_title");
});

where .act_title{color: red;} but not work

Comment: Be interesting to see @Shilly' s css-only solution.   CSS doesn't tend do well with "given this change some semi-related element in a completely different section of the document".  Given the HTML layout provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the right selector for you `a` --> `a[data-id="2"]`
2. Use the [jquery hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to act on it when hovered
3. Find the selector for your `div` --> `.left_box div[data-id="2"]`
4. Get its color by using [jquery CSS](https://api.jquery.com/css/)
5. Change the color of your link using the same method.

   $('a[data-id="2"]').hover(function(event) {
   $(event.target).css("color", $('.left_box div[data-id="2"]').css("color"));
   })

Comment: $('a[data-id="2"]').hover(function(event) { $(event.target).css("color", $('.left_box a[data-id="2"]').css("color: red")); });

is correct? because not work

Comment: Yes it does. You need to unset the value when leaving, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/be0vazfg/

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript solution:

Uses `querySelectorAll` to get all the `.right_box > a[data-id]`

Then get the id from `e.dataset.id` and use that to find it's *friend*

Then apply `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` to change any styling you'd like

```js
const ee = document.querySelectorAll('.right_box > a[data-id]')

for (let e of ee) {
  let friend = document.querySelector(`div[data-id="${e.dataset.id}"]`)
  e.onmouseover =  () => friend.style.color = 'red';
  e.onmouseleave = () => friend.style.color = 'unset';
}
```

```html
<div class="left_box">
    <div data-id="1">
        title 1
     </div>
     <div data-id="2">
        title 2
     </div>
     <div data-id="3">
        title 3
     </div>
</div>
<div class="right_box">
    <a href="#" data-id="1">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-id="3">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-id="2">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
 </div>
```

---

Based on OP's comment; same idea using `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`

```js
const ee = document.querySelectorAll('.right_box > a[data-id]')

for (let e of ee) {
  let friend = document.querySelector(`div[data-id="${e.dataset.id}"]`)
  e.onmousedown =  () => friend.style.color = 'red';
  e.onmouseup = () => friend.style.color = 'unset';
}
```

```html
<div class="left_box">
    <div data-id="1">
        title 1
     </div>
     <div data-id="2">
        title 2
     </div>
     <div data-id="3">
        title 3
     </div>
</div>
<div class="right_box">
    <a href="#" data-id="1">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-id="3">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-id="2">
       <img src="url_image">
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: is possibile to change code with onclick and not in hover? I need when I click add class and remove (es: on click data-id="1" add class to other box with data-id="1" ecc...)

Comment: I've added a second snippet below my answer @WebsiteDeveloper.

Comment: ok but I need to change class when I click on other box

Comment: Es: on click data-id="1" => add class other box data-id="1"
on click data-id="2" => remove class of data-id="1" and add class other div data-id="2"

Answer (score 0):

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) solution.   Within the hover callback, get the id of the element being hovered with

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

then your "title" selector becomes:

```
$(`.left_box > div[data-id='${id}']`)
```

without the variable, this would generate the selector: `.left_box > div[data-id='2']`

Updated snippet:

```js
$(".right_box a").hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(`.left_box > div[data-id='${id}']`).addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(`.left_box > div[data-id='${id}']`).removeClass("hover");
  })
```

```css
.hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_box">
  <div data-id="1">
    title 1
  </div>
  <div data-id="2">
    title 2
  </div>
  <div data-id="3">
    title 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right_box">
  <a href="#" data-id="1">
    <img src="url_image">
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-id="3">
    <img src="url_image">
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-id="2">
    <img src="url_image">
  </a>
</div>
```